# Ruby Net/sftp gem - Establishes and creates file, but 0 byte is uploaded

Tags: ruby, ftp, sftp, net-ftp

I'm trying to make a script in Ruby that can uploads a local file to a ftp server using a sftp connection.

The script establishes a connection to the server and creates the file just fine. The problem is that the file it not uploaded correctly. The filesize continues to be 0 bytes.

Here is the script:

```
require 'net/sftp'

Net::SFTP.start("HOST", 'USERNAME', :password => 'PASSWORD', :verbose => Logger::DEBUG) do |sftp|
 sftp.upload!("/LOCAL/PATH/TO/FILE", "/REMOTE/PATH/TO/FILE")
end
```

When I am using Filezilla it works without any problems.

I am currently using the **Net/sftp gem** - [Net/sftp - github site](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-sftp)

I have opened port 21 and 22 on the server and given read/write permission to the user.

Am I missing something? I don't see any errors.
Please tell me if I can provide you with any other information that might help you answering my question.